# Testing Different Wifi Vendors - Strategies

Tags: wifi, testing

I am currently looking to trial some new Wifi products for my work place.  We currently have around 50 Access Points that link into an HP MSM controller.

I wanted to find out if anyone has any strategies to test the different products, for example load testing, signal tests, management.

The products I am currently looking at are Aruba and Meraki. Management is an easy one to test, looking at Aruba with AirWave and obviously Meraki has it's built in Management portal.

Comment: The management is the part that will be most distinctive as APs are not that different from one brand to another in terms of performance as they almost all follow the protocol and specifications to the letter.

Comment: I suppose what I meant is that the management part will be easy to compare.

Comment: I know but my point was that you're on a quest in finding the best of the best while they will likely all have very similar outcomes, so you'll have wasted much time and effort.

Comment: So you suggest that a Meraki AP and a Aruba AP should perform much the same, given that they are of similar specs, and I should focus my attention on the software features, such as visibility, ease of use and deployment, etc.

Comment: That is exactly my point.  Perhaps you could do a few tests to compare between your two final choices but the software implementation is probably what will determine your final choice anyway.